# Pigeonhole Principle: How many solutions for equation?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm revising for a test and the following problem using pigeonhole principle has me scratching my head for hours.

Given the equation $a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_i = n$, where $i$ and $n$ being positive integers, and $n \ge i$. Find out how many solutions are there in the positive integers.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Pigeonhole Principle tells us that there is at least one solution.  However, this is a combinations with repetition problem.

Comment: I see, so it isn't a Pigeonhole principle problem. My study group told me that it was so, so maybe all of us were wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that each $a_k$, $1 \leq k \leq i$, is a nonnegative integer?

Comment: Yes, all are positive integers.

Comment: Just to clarify, the nonnegative integers include zero, while the positive integers do not.  Do you want the number of solutions in the nonnegative integers, the positive integers, or both?

Comment: Woops, I meant just positive integers, zero and negative integers not included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $n \geq i$, the Pigeonhole Principle tells us that the equation 
$$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \ldots + a_i = n$$
has at least one solution in the positive integers.

To determine the number of solutions, it helps to consider an example.  Suppose $n = 10$ and $i = 4$.  Then we wish to find the number of solutions of the equation 
$$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 = 10$$
in the positive integers.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of three addition signs in the nine spaces between successive ones in a row of ten ones.  For instance, 
$$1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 2$, $a_3 = 3$, and $a_4 = 4$.  Therefore, the number of solutions of the equation $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 = 10$ is $\binom{9}{3}$.

We wish to find the number of solutions of the equation 
$$a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_i = n$$
in the positive integers.  How many spaces are there in which we can place an addition sign between successive ones in a row of $n$ ones?  How many addition signs do we need to place in those spaces?  Can you now write down a general formula?

Comment: Just the clarify, what do you mean by "nine spaces between successive ones in a row of ten ones."?

Comment: Here is a picture.  The squares are in the spaces between successive ones.  $$1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1$$

Comment: Woah, thank you so much for the in-depth clarification, detailed answers, and patience. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to know the number of solutions to $x + y + z = 5$, where $x, y, z \ge 0$  Every solution can be represented like so:

`ooxooox  (2,3,0)`

Can you do the rest?

Comment: Is that writing out all possible solutions, or is it some form of notation? (I have never seen that before) Sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: In asking for a clarification, I learned that the OP meant the number of solutions in the positive integers rather than the nonnegative integers.

Comment: That is an easy modification on this solution. First use up one in each box. The allocatee the rest.